# Better .htaccess tip

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want the link 'website.com/abc' to redirect to 'website.com/profile.php?user_username=abc&current_user=xyz'. Can I do this using .htaccess? If so, how?

I had tried using various tutorials but all I could find is to redirect 'website.com/abc' to 'website.com/profile.php?user_username=abc'. But the addition string in the url '&current_user=xyz' is troubling me.

Any help?

Further information,
current_user: the user in the session (the current logged in user)
user_username: the user whose profile has been visited by the current_user

Comment: Is current user the PHP logged in user? If so, to my knowledge, that's not possible. You could just use the logged in user in the profile page.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Apache does not have access to the users' cookies. You would want to create website.com/abc/index.php that does a redirect for you using the [`header()`](http://php.net/header) function.